# UnknownError: javascript error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Trying to create a protractor test for my angular app, this is the service I am trying to call from my Jasmine script:

```
var app =angular.module('app',[]);

app.factory('myService', function($http) {
        var myService = {
            async: function() {
                // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
                var promise = $http.get('test.json').then(function (response) {
                    // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
                    console.log(response);
                    // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
                    return response.data;
                });
                // Return the promise to the controller
                return promise;
            }
        };
        return myService;
    });

;
```

My spec is defined like this:

```
it('should call api i the site', function () {
    browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback) {
    var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    var myService = angular.injector(['ng']).get('myService');
    myService.async().then(function (d) {
            $scope.data = d;
    });
    callback(null, true);
    });
})
```

When I run the script the line that contains angular.injector(['ng']).get('myService') results in this error:

```
UnknownError: javascript error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myServiceProvider <- myService
```

What is the right injector statement?

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
var injector = angular.injector(['app', 'ng']);
var myService = injector.get('myService');
```

Comment: when I do that I get: UnknownError: javascript error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $compileProvider

Comment: It's been a while, but changing the order of `['app', 'ng']` to `['ng', 'app']` should fix the problem.